# Excel print area/formatting issues across different Computers

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I programmed a reporting tool in VBA. It does structure some data and then puts together a report. The report only consists of shapes, pictures and charts, i.e. no information is stored in cells.

All elements are either already the report sheet or get positioned by using the .left and .top properties. In the end, the sheet gets exported as a pdf. It is a nice two pager, at least on my computer and a different one I have access to.

However, when a collegue tries to run the code on his computer (exact same Excel version), the output gets distorted. It does not fit on two pages anymore (in height) and some elements (charts and tables inserted as pictures) are not on the exact same positions where they should be.

It looks like the fixed elements that are already on the report sheet are compressed horizontally so that they get to high for the pages (the fit the page width in the output). All the other elements are put where they belong but do not fit the compressed page anymore. I cant show you the real thing, but I made one part of the report unreadable to show it to you. (And I have put red text and arrows to explain the issue)

[image]

I dont have access to the computer that produces the flawed output, only to the pdfs it produces.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, as the print area and page properties are defined in the workbook itslef, and should not change. Also .Top and .Left positions should be accurate everywhere.

Maybe somone has experienced something similiar and can give me hint. Thanks.

Comment: I did not do that yet, but I will have a look at it. I think I will force fixed options in my code. Thanks for the hint, I will tell when I have results.